# How can I convert NSData to C string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

How can I convert `[NSString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]` result to C string?

> Returns an NSData object containing a representation of the receiver encoded using a given encoding.

```
- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding allowLossyConversion:(BOOL)flag
```

> Note that the data returned by dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:
>   is not a strict C-string since it **does not have a NULL terminator**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSMutableData *data = [[@"foo" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] mutableCopy];
char nul = '\0';
[data appendBytes:&nul length:sizeof(nul)];
const char *cString = [data bytes];
```

Or, simply:

```
const char *cString = [@"foo" UTF8String];
```

... with exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [**`-[NSString cStringUsingEncoding:]`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/cStringUsingEncoding%3a) method that sounds promising.

Comment: It returns nil instead `allowLossyConversion:YES` string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are asking the wrong question.

```
NSString* myString = @"Whatever";
const char* utf8String = [myString UTF8String];
```

Quite pointless to go through NSData.

Comment: the OP needs to allow **lossy conversion** that's why goes through NSData